# Domain controller infected with ransomware. How to transfer DC clients to a new domain?

Tags: active-directory, user-profiles, windows-server-2019

Our company DC got infected with a ransomware & now unable to access to it. Is there any solution to transfer DC clients to a new DC without losing their user existing profiles? Need an urgent solution. I've Googled but couldn't find any solution yet. please help me out.

Comment: This sounds like any suggestion to simply swap in the last uninfected backup will be met with 'but we don't have a backup.'

Comment: The backup file also infected as it was backed up to the same computer. :(

Comment: I imagine that strategy will change in future:\ Bear in mind the adage that "Any data not stored in at least three distinct locations ought to be considered temporary." Yours was all in one location, which is functionally the same as not having a backup at all.

Comment: Understood. So any solution to move previous domain clients to new DC?

Comment: None that I know of, sorry [which doesn't mean one doesn't exist, I just don't know of one.]